# Dockerfile ADD and COPY do not work properly

Tags: dockerfile

We have a vagrant machine running under windows 10.
Inside that vagrant, we want to create a docker image using a Dockerfile.

Version of docker inside the vagrant is:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604
```

The docker file is this one:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir ~/opt
COPY test.tgz ~/opt/.
RUN ls -la ~/opt/.

ADD ./test.tgz ~/opt/.

RUN cd ~/opt/. &&\
  pwd &&\
  tar xvzf ./test.tgz
```

and the output of the image creation command:

```
$ docker build -t frojasg1/test:20210601 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 9ff95a467e45
Step 2 : RUN mkdir ~/opt
 ---> Running in caee3cbc00e0
 ---> 73a0a9da81ba
Removing intermediate container caee3cbc00e0
Step 3 : COPY test.tgz ~/opt/.
 ---> e4e413ad3bab
Removing intermediate container fa81c5ef7775
Step 4 : RUN ls -la ~/opt/.
 ---> Running in 82897cb5c488
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  1 09:40 .
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Jun  1 09:40 ..
 ---> 143f6660707e
Removing intermediate container 82897cb5c488
Step 5 : ADD ./test.tgz ~/opt/.
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e68ae154a12a660708f7a348ed09ebf01cd10177617141312bc70c4af88637ae/rootfs/~/opt/.pivot_root077529346: not a directory
```

You can download the whole directory contents at:
https://frojasg1.com/stackoverflow/20210601.dockerfile/test.zip

Does anyone know what is happening ?

Comment: why do you require ``ADD ./test.tgz ~/opt/.
`` . You already did a COPY before. So you can remove the line `ADD ./test.tgz ~/opt/.
``

Comment: I wanted to  check both COPY and ADD
The output shows that the file is not copied, and after that, it fails at ADD command.

Comment: there seems to be an extra . in your COPY command at last.Can you just execute COPY test.tgz ~/opt/

Comment: does it work for you

Comment: Thank you Altaf for your answer.
We have continued trying to execute the Dockerfile, and we have seen that the problem was the ~
I will answer my own question with the progress we have made

Answer (score 0):

We have finally been able to debug the problem:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.096 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 9ff95a467e45
Step 2 : RUN mkdir ~/opt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8da7855961a7
Step 3 : COPY test.tgz ~/opt/.
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 46acb39109cc
Step 4 : RUN ls -la ~/opt/.
 ---> Running in c4b7e327b8cf
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  2 10:25 .
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Jun  2 10:25 ..
 ---> c199f8b7b22d
Removing intermediate container c4b7e327b8cf
Step 5 : ADD ./test.tgz ~/opt/.
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/f7cb413cecaef0e0378c20e7de8d076512e993a6e8859d79ca2f73bfc5f11609/rootfs/~/opt/.pivot_root409667951: not a directory
```

to debug the problem, we have taken the latest intermediate image, and entered to see what had happened:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti 46acb39109cc /bin/bash
root@a3bb9ca87d90:/# ls -la ~
total 20
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jun  2 10:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jun  2 11:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 22  2015 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  2 10:25 opt
root@a3bb9ca87d90:/# pwd
/
root@a3bb9ca87d90:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  ~
root@a3bb9ca87d90:/# cd ~
root@a3bb9ca87d90:~# pwd
/root
root@a3bb9ca87d90:~# exit
exit
```

The problem is that folder a folder ~ is created at /
But when changing directory to ~, it locates at /root

The solution seems to change ~ by /root inside the Dockerfile (as the user is root in our Dockerfile)